# Kafka: can I put a path after the zookeeper port number?

Tags: connection-string, apache-kafka

The kafka server is configured with a path following the port number (from the server.properties)

```
zookeeper.connect=xxxxx007:2181/kafka
```

The java producer code:

```
Properties props = new Properties();
props.put("serializer.class", "kafka.serializer.StringEncoder");
props.put("metadata.broker.list", "xxxxx007:9092");
```

The producer populates the topic if the broker omits /kafka

The producer gets numberFormatException when the broker contains /kafa

```
Properties props = new Properties();
props.put("serializer.class", "kafka.serializer.StringEncoder");
props.put("metadata.broker.list", "xxxxx007:9092/kafka");
java.lang.NumberFormatException: For input string: "9092/kafka"
```

The java consumer hangs (returns no data) if the zookeeper connection contains /kafka

```
Properties props = new Properties();
props.put("zookeeper.connect", "xxxxx007:2181/kafka");
```

The java consumer gets exception if the zookeeper connection omits /kakfa

```
Properties props = new Properties();
props.put("zookeeper.connect", "xxxxx007:2181");
Exception in thread "main" kafka.common.ConsumerRebalanceFailedException:    group1_BFTSLBHW0000RGU-1397591737558-f75b6658 can't rebalance after 4 retries
at kafka.consumer.ZookeeperConsumerConnector$ZKRebalancerListener.syncedRebalance(ZookeeperConsumerConnector.scala:428)
at kafka.consumer.ZookeeperConsumerConnector.kafka$consumer$ZookeeperConsumerConnector$$reinitializeConsumer(ZookeeperConsumerConnector.scala:718)
at kafka.consumer.ZookeeperConsumerConnector.consume(ZookeeperConsumerConnector.scala:209)
at kafka.javaapi.consumer.ZookeeperConsumerConnector.createMessageStreams(ZookeeperConsumerConnector.scala:80)
at kafka.javaapi.consumer.ZookeeperConsumerConnector.createMessageStreams(ZookeeperConsumerConnector.scala:92)
at kafka.examples.TitaniumConsumer.main(TitaniumConsumer.java:73)
```

Answer (score 0):

The intention behind specifying this zookeeper path is so that for a particular cluster all data available in kafka appear under this particular path. 
[Note that you must create this path yourself prior to starting the broker and consumers must use the same connection string.](http://kafka.apache.org/08/configuration.html)

Comment: using `zkCli.sh` you can create the path by `create /kafka ""`.